# Popup for Jwplayer to display video

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, popup, jwplayer

i have a project in which i am require to display a video, i have used a jwplayer to show mp4 and flv video as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var s = '<%=this.Finalpath %>';
        if (s) {
            jwplayer("mediaplayerid").setup({
                flashplayer: '<%= ResolveUrl("Jwplayer/player.swf") %>',
                provider: "video",
                file: s,
                autostart: true,
                width: '380',
                height: '200'
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

now the requirement is to show the video or jwplayer in a popup window. i have google it for hours and found various boxes. i am confuse with the method of which box to use and how to integrate it. please share your knowledge in this respect. thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The method that you can use to show it on a popup window is actually to place it inside a div, or if its an outside page with video, like the YouTube, to place it inside a div that contains an iframe, and the iframe loads that page with the video. Now the main div is formatted and displayed as poupwindow inside the page.

There are many all ready existing libraries that you can use to do that.

One is the highslide: http://highslide.com/#examples

On this page you can see the two examples the "display flash" and the "YouTube w/fade effect" that you can use as they are to make it work.

Comment: Actually sir i am uploading a video to the server. That video need to be played at popup. how this logic need to be implemented

Comment: @Abhishekgupta after the upload, you open the popup windows using javascript. On this popup you change the video url to the one you just uploaded. Start on how to show it, then make the upload, then after the upload finish make the logic that open the popup.